# Oracle apex birthday calendar

Tags: oracle-apex

I created a birthday calendar in apex 20.2 but  i came up against with a problem. Is it possible to make a search by name? I have no idea how to do it. Maybe it should be displayed on a certain list, idk. Thank in advance!

I created a select list and write process

Comment: If you explained what "birthday calendar" is, how it is related to "search by name" (name? Calendars have days and months, not personal names), possibly posted a screenshot which illustrates it, maybe we'd be able to assist. I can't, not at the moment.

Comment: @Littlefoot it's just a simple calendar with names and departments of our staff. I need to add an opportunity to search names in calendar

Comment: Sorry, I can't imagine what you are trying to describe and can't suggest anything that would help you solve that problem. Screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

So ... suppose we create a birthday calendar based on the EMP table. That would show us months that we can paginate through with the days on which it is someone 's birthday highlighted.
Now... suppose we search for "KING". What is the expected output ? If you search for one person, then it doesn't make sense to display a calendar. It would make sense to show a report instead.

What you could do is

- Generate a calendar with the birthdays
- Add a page item P1_NAME to your page
- Add a report (IR or Classic) to the page with query

```
  SELECT name, date_of_birth FROM the_birtday_table WHERE UPPER(name) like '%'||UPPER(:P1_NAME)||'%'
```

- Make sure "items to submit" attribute of the report has P1_NAME in it.
- Add a dynamic action (on change of) page item P1_NAME with actions to

  - Show the calendar if P1_NAME is null (client condition)
  - Hide the report if P1_NAME is null (client condition)
  - Show the report if P1_NAME is not null (client condition)
  - Refresh the report if P1_NAME is not null (client condition)
  - Hide the report if P1_NAME is not null (client condition)